# autofill from one field filling in another

Tags: php

I have a date field that needs to fill in a select with some times registered on that date, however, I'm using this.form.submit(); but the submit saves the file, how can I get the times in a select of that date?
if I remove the "pre-aplicar.php" the schedules come correctly

```
<form action="pre-aplicar.php" method="post" name="frm_cadastro" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr>
  <td id="label" valign=top>Data</td>
  <td id="home" valign=top><input type="date" name="cp_data" onChange="this.form.submit();" value="<? echo $_POST['cp_data']; ?>"></td>
</tr> 

<tr>
  <td id="label" valign=top>Horário</td>

  <td id="home" valign=top>
    <select name="cp_horario" id="cp_horario" >

      <?php

      echo "<option value=\"\" style=\"color:silver;\">:: selecione ::</option>";

          foreach( $ARRAY_HORARIOS as $key => $itemHorario ){

            echo "<option value=\"" . $itemHorario[ "cg_id" ] . "\" $sel>" . $itemHorario[ "cg_janela" ] . "</option>";
    
          }

      ?>

    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understood your question correctly, you don't want form to be submitted the classical way. you can do something like the following, and if at all submission is needed, submit via javascript

```
<form name="myFormName" id="myFormId" onsubmit="javascript:return false">
```

Comment: so, in the bank I have the dates with the time windows, I want that when I select a date in the select, the times of that date I want come